# Not able to use web inspector on blackberry 7.0 device

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I Followed below steps to use web inspector on my 7.0 device.

1.Build my web works app with following command.

```
bbwp test.zip -d -o C:\Output\test
```

Note: I did not use -g  option becuase i read somewhere that i cannot debug if i sign the app.

2.Load to device with following command.

```
JavaLoader load C:\Output\StandardInstall\App.cod
```

App is loaded to the device successfully.

**When i try to open the Application It doesn't alert the IP address and port number.
Instead it alerts "Error starting xxxApp:Module 'xxApp' attempts to access a secure API."**

My dear Experts please let me know what is wrong with the procedure i am following.

One more observation i made is i tried to enable Web Inspector on my browser(device) as mentioned in below link.

http://www.berryreview.com/2011/11/18/blackberry-os-7-web-inspector-easily-debug-blackberry-websites-webworks-browser-apps/

but after step 5(You will now need to hit the menu button again and select Developer Tools –> Enable Web Inspector) i don't see my device alerting IP address and Port number !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your error is because you have not signed your application. Follow steps from here https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup.html You were misinformed about signing, you most definitely can debug a signed application.
- Your last problem(in which the prompt doesn't display) might be related to your network connection. Ensure you are connected over wifi. Otherwise an IP won't be assigned and the prompt won't pop up when you start your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated with edits by @jeffheifetz, which were unfortunately rejected.

Comment: If i use USB cable will i not be able to use web inspector ? Unfortunately i don't have wifi . how shall i debug :( ? please help.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's the case. You will be able to grab the logs however which should be of some use.  If you test using the simulator you can simply go to tools > show output logs. For the device, see instructions here: https://www.impaticize.com/impkb/questions/175/  Good luck anyway, hope I've helped. If I've answered your question please mark my answer as correct.